# Is is possible to real time update a value with spark streaming?

Tags: statistics, apache-spark, streaming

Lets assume I have a stream of Double values and I want to compute the average every ten seconds. How can I have a sliding window that doesn't need to recompute the average but instead update it by, lets say, removing the part of the oldest ten seconds and adding only the new 10 seconds values?

Comment: Could you please add an example...

Comment: Yeah sure. Let's assume I have to compute an average every 2 seconds with data that are coming from a stream but in a window of 1 hour. Which means that I want, every 2 seconds to exclude the data that are now out of the window and include the new ones but without recomputing all the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read) : use `reduceByWindow` with both of its function arguments (jump to the last paragraph for the code snippet)

There's two interpretations of your question, the specific one (how do I get a running mean for one hour, updated every 2 seconds), and the general one (how do I get a computation that updates state in a sparse way). Here's the answer for the general one.

First, notice there is a way to represent your data such that your average-with-updates is easy to compute, based on a [windowed DStream](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/windows.html): this represents your data as an incremental construction of the stream, with maximal sharing. But it is less efficient, computationally, to recompute the mean on each batch – as you noted.

If you do want to do an update of a complex stateful computation which is invertible, but don't want to touch the stream's construction, there is [`updateStateByKey`](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html) – but there Spark doesn't help you in reflecting the incremental aspect of your computation in the stream, you have to manage it yourself.

Here, you do have something simple and invertible, and you don't have a notion of keys. You can use [`reduceByWindow`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream) with its inverse reduction argument, using the usual functions that would let you compute an incremental mean.

```
val myInitialDStream: DStream[Float]

val myDStreamWithCount: DStream[(Float, Long)] = 
  myInitialDStream.map((x) => (x, 1L))

def addOneBatchToMean(previousMean: (Float, Long), newBatch: (Float, Long)): (Float, Long) = 
  (previousMean._1 + newBatch._1, previousMean._2 + newBatch._2)

def removeOneBatchToMean(previousMean: (Float, Long), oldBatch: (Float, Long)): (Float, Long) = 
  (previousMean._1 - oldBatch._1, previousMean._2 - oldBatch._2)

val runningMeans = myDStreamWithCount.reduceByWindow(addOneBatchToMean, removeOneBatchToMean, Durations.seconds(3600), Duractions.seconds(2))
```

You get a stream of one-element `RDD`s, each of which contains a pair (m, n) where m is your running sum over the 1h-window and n the number of elements in the 1h-window. Just return (or `map` to) m/n to get the mean.